# Pointdns with heroku invalid dns point

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns

I have deployed my app on heroku and got a custom domain with pointdns.
point dns seems to redirect the doamin correctly, but heroku seems to get invalid app or empty page that says " There's nothing here, yet. ".

[my doamin dns records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ccN.png)

[heroku error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb2YM.png)

[point dns records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLPr4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just CNAME the domain at `n5hl.herokuapp.com`.

You need to go to the Heroku settings for the app, add a custom domain, and point the DNS at the *specific* CNAME record they give you. (It'll be something like `foo-bar-random-string.herokudns.com`.)

Comment: i know i could do that, but unlikely my domain provider doesn't support CNAME dns so i have to use pointdns .

Comment: @N05h3ll You do this *in* PointDNS. You've just used the wrong value for the CNAME there. Your domain provider is irrelevant.

Comment: so i point my custom domain in pointdns to the CNAME from heroku, is that right ?

Comment: i have updated my CNAME on pointdns like this picture https://imgur.com/a/Yq46AlM  for a while now but still nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Adding both

```
<mydomain>.cf
```

and

```
 www.<mydomain>.cf
```

to heroku custom domains solved the problem.

Comment: shouldn't this be the first step